# ManyToOne on queryBuilder symfony 3

Tags: symfony, search, doctrine-orm, query-builder, many-to-one

I have 2 entities `Federation` and `Pays` , the entity `Federation` has a property `ManyToOne`:

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stage\AdminBundle\Entity\Pays")
     */
    public $nomPays;
```

I want to build a query using `QueryBuilder` to get all the rows based on a search with that property `$nomPays`.

I tried:

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Federation::class);

 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('f')
     ->leftJoin('StageAdminBundle:Pays', 'fc', 'f.id = fc.id')
     ->Where('f.nomPays = :value')
     ->setParameter('value', '%'.$term.'%')
     ->orderBy('f.nom', 'ASC')
     ->getQuery();

 $federations = $query->getResult();
```

The problem is that there is 0 result and no row is showed, but when I do a search based on another property of the entity the result is showed and there is no error .

I just want to know if there is something wrong that i didnt notice.

Comment: maybe you should use small letter where instead of capital letter Where

Comment: still the same result ,thanks for your attention

Comment: Have your data in database?

Comment: Your query the semantically wrong your, post your both entity definitions and also add some brief regarding your search criteria

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong is here `'f.id = fc.id'`:

```
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Federation::class);

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('f')
            ->leftJoin('StageAdminBundle:Pays', 'fc', 'f.nomPays = fc.id')
            ->where('f.nomPays = :value')

            ->setParameter('value', '%'.$term.'%')
            ->orderBy('f.nom', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();
          $federations = $query->getResult();
```